# Process syncronization VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hardware

Since in VHDL a process is a collection of sequential statements and if write more than one process these ones are executed concurrently is it possible to sync. them?

As example

```
architeture my_arch_is of my_entity is
begin
    proc_1 : process(...)
    begin
       -- code
    end process;

    proc_2 : process(...)
    begin
       -- code
    end process;

    proc_3 : process(...)
    begin
       -- code
    end process;
end architecture;
```

What i would like to achieve is the following, the process 1 is a kind of selector (i.e. it assigns a bit under a specific event) process 2 and 3 instead compute in parallel two possible result, basically i would like to compute the selector and both the results and using another vhdl construct say something like "if selector is 0 take the result of process 2, otherwise take the result of process 3", like a multiplexer.

Is it possible to do something like that (if it does make sense of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. And if you use for example, a conditional statement for selecting one of the two results, given the bit value provided by process 1, it will actually be synthesized as a multiplexer.

Comment: I know it is a trivial question... but since i'm a newbie i still have some problem with the understanding of process and how they work. Should i create a fourth process for the selection? I think of yes since the conditional statement is a sequential statement, but just to be sure.

Comment: You don't have to create a fourth process for that. You can use any of the concurrent assignment statements for this purpose. Conditional assignment is one of them.

Comment: Again... i think the idea should be something like... each process assign its OWN signals, and the final conditional statement should set the final signal. Isn't? i cannot work on the same signal in more than one process block isn't?

Comment: As long as you don't assign to the same signal in more than one process block, its fine. In your case you're only reading the signal values from the given processes, and assigning a value to a new signal based on those values.